# Creating a list of ActiveRecord associations for different types of "task" objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I currently have a generic task table called `tasks` that contains the essentials of what any task would require (common attributes).

```
  create_table "tasks", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "agent_id"
    t.datetime "start"
    t.text     "note"
    t.string   "status"
    t.datetime "create_date"
  end
```

I also have multiple types of tasks that I want related to a `tasks` object, such as `followup` and `review_sales_office`. Both of these will contain different details, but they are all technically types of `tasks`.

```
  create_table "followups", force: true do |t|
    t.integer "account_id"
    t.integer "task_id"
    t.integer "account_contact_id"
    t.string  "contact_method"
  end

  create_table "review_sales_offices", force: true do |t|
    t.integer "sales_office_id"
    t.integer "task_id"
    t.integer "sales_office_rep"
  end
```

These all work fine if I just want to grab a list of all followup tasks, or a list of all reviews sales office tasks, but how would I go about retrieving a list of all tasks sorted by task_datetime that when output to a view would be clickable to the respective type of task (task 1 and 2 might be a followup, task 3 might be a sales office review).

I can do a `Task.joins(...)` to get a collection of all tasks (which I think is the correct way to do this), but the task itself isn't necessarily aware of the type of task it is, so I'm not sure how I would generate the appropriate link based on the task type (the link would ideally go to something like an edit page for the appropriate task type).

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Word of the day is: polymorphic association!

All you need is:

1) Add task_details_type:string and task_details_id columns to your Task table.

2) Add in your Task model

```
belongs_to :task_details, polymorphic: true
```

3) In each Task type add:

```
has_one :task, as: task_details
```

And you have a simple model, which will give right task_details without you concerning of its type. In additon you can make it a wrapper:

```
def method_missing(name, args*, &block)
  return task_details.public_send(name, *args, &block) if task_details && task_details.respond_to? name
  super
end
```

Unfortunately it is not possible to declare polymorphic has_one association, so we need to live with putting nonsenses like 'task belongs_to task_details' - tough live.

Comment: Wouldn't this result in foreign keys at both ends, almost like a has_and_belongs_to_many without the join table? Is that an issue?

Comment: You can get rid of foreign keys on 'typed' tables, they won't be used at all. All other associations between those types are obsolete with the above.

Comment: @AlecSanger In your case, you would ditch the foreign key columns in the concrete types as they are no longer needed. So in effect, the relationship will now go the other direction (from `tasks` to [concrete type]).

Comment: Worked great. Thanks to the both of you.